# Invariant metrics on homogeneous spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $M$ be a compact homogeneous space given by $K/N$, where $ K=G \times \mathbb{T}^n / H $, $G$ is a simply connected compact Lie group, $\mathbb{T}^n$ the $n$-torus and $H$ is a central finite subgroup of $G \times \mathbb{T}^n$ and $N$ is a closed subgroup of $K$.

Every biinvariant metric on $K$ induces a $K$-invariant metric on $M$. $(\ast)$

- Can we realize every $K$-invariant metric on $M$ in this way?
- If not: Can we characterize the Lie groups $K$ and closed subgroups $N$ such that all $K$-invariant metrics on $M$ are induced by biinvariant metrics of $K$?
- If not: Can we distinguish the $K$-invariant metrics on $M$, which are given by $(\ast)$ by curvature conditions from the metrics which do not satisfy $(\ast)$?